# concatenation of arrays in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

I wrote a code for concatenation as below:

```
module p2;

int n[1:2][1:3] = {2{{3{1}}}};

initial
begin
$display("val:%d",n[2][1]);
end

endmodule
```

It is showing errors.
Please explain?

Comment: What error? What do you think `n[1:2][1:3] = {2{{3{1}}}};` means?

Comment: I meant,  
n[1:2][1:3]={{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}
But, i got the answer.
n[1:2][1:3]='{'{1,1,1},'{1,1,1}}  
This is the correct one.

Comment: Glad you got your answer, I was trying to emphasize the unpacked array (on the left) vs packed array (on the right).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unpacked arrays require a `'{}` format. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 5.11 (or search for `'{` in the LRM for many examples).

Therefore update your assignment to:

```
int n[1:2][1:3] = '{2{'{3{1}}}};
```

Comment: The single quote in front of the open curly bracket without a cast_type next to the single quote (ex `'{1,2,3}` but not `int'{1,2,3}`) is essentially doing a type cast to unpacked array. &sect; 10.9.1 does a better job explaining it then &sect; 5.11 but still a limited description.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n[1:2][1:3] = {2{{3{1}}}};
```

Just looking at `{3{1}}` this is a 96 bit number 3 integers concatenated together.
It is likely that `{3{1'b1}}` was intended.

The main issue looks to be the the left hand side is an unpacked array, and the left hand side   is a packed array.

```
  { 2 { {3{1'b1}} } } => 6'b111_111
```

What is required is [[3'b111],[3'b111]],

From IEEE std 1800-2009 the array assignments section will be of interest here

> **10.9.1 Array assignment patterns**
>   Concatenation braces are used to construct and deconstruct simple bit vectors. 
>   A similar syntax is used to support the construction and deconstruction of arrays. The expressions shall match element for element, and the braces shall match the array dimensions. Each expression item shall be evaluated in the context of an
>   assignment to the type of the corresponding element in the array. In other words, the following examples are not required to cause size warnings:

```
bit unpackedbits [1:0] = '{1,1};        // no size warning required as
                                        // bit can be set to 1
int unpackedints [1:0] = '{1'b1, 1'b1}; // no size warning required as 
                                        // int can be set to 1’b1
```

> A syntax resembling replications (see 11.4.12.1) can be used in array assignment patterns as well. Each replication shall represent an entire single dimension.

```
unpackedbits    = '{2 {y}} ;     // same as '{y, y}
int n[1:2][1:3] = '{2{'{3{y}}}}; // same as '{'{y,y,y},'{y,y,y}}
```